# How to create an array of every nth item?

Tags: php

Say I have the following table:

```
name
----
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
```

I can extract this from MySQL and put it in an array:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY name DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
  $names[] = $row->name
}
```

What I am now looking for is a script that loops through `$names` and returns pairs, for instance every 3rd name:

```
array(
  [A] => [C],
  [B] => [D],
  [C] => [E],
  [D] => [F]
  [E] => [G]
  [F] => [H]
  [G] => [I]
)
```

Or, for instance, every 4th name:

```
array(
  [A] => [D],
  [B] => [E],
  [C] => [F],
  [D] => [G]
  [E] => [H]
  [F] => [I]
)
```

The number of names in between (3 in the fist example, 4 in the second) should be variable. Does anybody know how to do this in php?

Comment: MySQL extension is [deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), can lead to serious security issues and will eventually be removed from PHP altogether. Consider using [other](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) extension.

Comment: What should happen if there are an odd number of results?

Comment: @Makita I don't understand your question. I believe both my examples have an odd number of results? Whatever doesn't fit as a pair in the array, should be disgarded. For instance, in the first example `H` and `I` are now being used, in the second example `I` is disgarded. I hope this answers your question...

Comment: @norfavrell In rreality, I already use another extension with a wrapper but I thought this code would most easily be understood by people :-)

Comment: Why doesn't the first array have `[F] => [H]` and `[G] => [I]`, or the second array have `[F] => [I]` ?

Comment: @salathe Because I made a mistake. You are right. Edited the post :-) Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a fairly simple for loop.

Here's an example. All you need to do is tweak `$seperation`:

```
<?php

$array = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I');
$seperation = 3;
$assoc = array(); // stores result

for($i = 0; $i+$seperation < count($array); $i++) {
   $assoc[$array[$i]] = $array[$i + $seperation];
}

print_r($assoc);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/jHMUfvwP)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) and [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) functions to create the key/value pairs that you are wanting.

```
function array_nth(array $array, $nth)
{
    $keys   = array_slice($array, 0, -($nth - 1));
    $values = array_slice($array, $nth - 1);
    return array_combine($keys, $values);
}
```

For example,

```
$names = range('A', 'I');
var_export(array_nth($names, 3));
```

Gives

```
array (
  'A' => 'C',
  'B' => 'D',
  'C' => 'E',
  'D' => 'F',
  'E' => 'G',
  'F' => 'H',
  'G' => 'I',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming these are indexed (by number)? Since in your example you just list [a, b, c]. Something like (might have an off by one bug but this is the idea):

```
function pairs($arr, $offset) {
    $rv = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < (sizeof($arr) - $offset); $i++) {
        $rv[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i + $offset];
    }
    return $rv;
}
```

Think it's pretty self explanatory. `(sizeof($arr) - $offset)` just makes sure you don't go off the end whne you have the `$arr[$i + $offset];`